# Creating an anoymous object in a class for linq query in C#

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to run a lot of linq queries and its good for me to run them in a constructor.

I have a query like :

```
var query = _cctDBContext.table1
                         .Select(b => new {
                             b.Id, 
                             b.SegmentId, 
                             b.Response1, 
                             b.ResponseDescription, 
                             b.ResponseGuidance})
                         .Where(b => b.SegmentId == SegmentId)
```

I know that is anonymous, but how could I execute this in a constructor?

Like this:

```
public class SegmentData
{
    private readonly sqldbCLSegImportUKSATPTestContext _clDBContext;
    private readonly sqldbCCTUKSATPTestContext _cctDBContext;
    private readonly IList<Response> ResponseCCTtoAuditResponse;

    public SegmentData(
        sqldbCLSegImportUKSATPTestContext clDBContext, 
        sqldbCCTUKSATPTestContext cctDBContext)
    {
        _clDBContext = clDBContext;
        _cctDBContext = cctDBContext;

        // AUDIT RESPONSE PAGE 15
        ResponseCCTtoAuditResponse = _cctDBContext.Response
                                                  .Select(b => new { 
                                                      b.ResponseId, 
                                                      b.SegmentId, 
                                                      b.Response1, 
                                                      b.ResponseDescription, 
                                                      b.ResponseGuidance})
                                                  .Where(b => b.SegmentId == 5)
                                                  .ToList();
    }
}
```

I have tried to assign the `IList` as the name of the Entity Framework class for the table and this does not work. Any help would be awesome

Comment: why do you even use anonymous objects? If you need to pass information from some place to another, you should provide string names for those things to make it easier for others to understand your code. Create a class that holds the selected information and create instances of that class for every item-.

Comment: It is not a good method to use anonymous objects? While passing data to other methods/pages /places you can create a class for that.

Comment: Fine i understand, perhaps you could give me an example as the classes are already created by EF Core. I am returning the linq as a ToList() - so a little help would be amazing.

Comment: instead of writing `new { b.ResponseId, b.SegmentId, b.Response1, b.ResponseDescription, b.ResponseGuidance}` just create a class with those properties and then wrte `new MyClass { ResponseId = b.ResponseId, ... }`.

Comment: I am trying to execute my linq in a constructor. I have each table as a class (as EF core creates them anyway) . I can do it with Var = all day but this doesnt seem the best way. I need to find a way to execute linq within a constructor . Can anyone provide me with a decent link or help in this ? It doesnt have to be anoymous.

Comment: "I can do it with Var = all day but this doesnt seem the best way" I don't undertand what you mean here. You have exactly one single query that projects one single (named) data-type. Maybe you can give a broader image of your setting.

Comment: `its good for me to run them in a constructor` - it's never good to run things in constructor. Constructor should be lightweight, it should only perform simple initializations and should not access DB. I don't know why do you have this projection but I think you can omit `Select` part and keep only `_cctDBContext.Response.Where(b => b.SegmentId == 5).ToList();`. If `Response` table has a lot of columns and you want to reduce retrieved data, follow @HimBromBeere's suggestion and create a class that have only required properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are concentrating on this query being run in a constructor for some reason. This has nothing to do with it.

Your query is creating a List of an anonymous class, and then trying to assign it to a List of a named, pre-defined class, Response. This won't work as they are different.

Instead of creating an anonymous type, *name the type in the query*:

```
ResponseCCTtoAuditResponse = _cctDBContext.Response.
          Select(b => new Response(){ ResponseId = b.ResponseId, 
                                      SegmentId = b.SegmentId,
                                      Response1 = b.Response1,
                                      ResponseDescription = b.ResponseDescription, 
                                      ResponseGuidance = b.ResponseGuidance}
                 ).Where(b => b.SegmentId == 5).ToList();
```

This assumes that the class you're selecting does have the same fields as the Response class, which you seem to be saying. Or use a different form of query:

```
ResponseCCTtoAuditResponse = (from r in cctDBContext.Response
                              where r.SegmentId == 5
                              select r).ToList<Response>();
```

Comment: this is perfect, so now i can excute the queries when the constructor fires... I see exactly how it works now and what i have done wrong...